# Series convergence or divergence $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n}\cos(3n)}{\sqrt{n^2 + 2}}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Can you give me some hint for the series
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n}\cos(3n)}{\sqrt{n^2 + 2}}
\end{align*} I have tried Leibniz test. It didn't help me.

Answer (score 4):

$\sum_\limits{n=1}^\infty \frac {1}{\sqrt{n^2 + 2}}$ can be compared to the harmonic series.  The harmonic series diverges... slowly.

The series is not absolutely convergent.  But, it still could be conditionally covergent.

The alternating series test doesn't help as $(-1)^n\cos 3n$ is not necessarily alternating.

That leaves Dirichlet's test.

If $\{a_n\}$ is a sequence of real numbers and $\{b_n\}$ is a sequence of complex numbers, such that:

$\{a_n\}$ is monotonic and $\lim_\limits{n\to\infty} a_n = 0$

And

$\forall N\in \mathbb N : \left|\sum_\limits{n=1}^N b_n \right|< M$ for some constant $M.$

$\sum_\limits{n=1}^\infty a_nb_n$ converges.

The first parts of the test, are easy enough and I will leave to you.

$(-1)^n\cos 3n = Re(e^{(3+\pi)in})$

And

$\left|\sum_\limits{n=1}^N Re(e^{(3+\pi)ni})\right| < \left|\sum_\limits{n=1}^N e^{(3+\pi)ni}\right|$

We still need to show that $\left|\sum_\limits{n=1}^N e^{(3+\pi)ni}\right|$ is bounded for all $N.$

$\sum_\limits{n=1}^N e^{(3+\pi)ni}$ is a geometric series.

$\sum_\limits{n=1}^N e^{(3+\pi)ni} =  e^{(3+\pi)i}\frac {1-e^{(3+\pi)Ni}}{1-e^{(3+\pi)i}}\\
\left| e^{(3+\pi)i}\frac {1-e^{(3+\pi)Ni}}{1-e^{(3+\pi)i}}\right| < 
\frac {2}{1+\cos 3}$

Comment: Why $e^{(3 + pi) ni)}$. Or you meant real part?

Comment: I think it is an easier problem to solve the way it is written.

Comment: @DougM I didn't understand your solution

Comment: @abc I have fleshed out the detail...

Comment: @DougM thank you. I didn't know inequality about real part and exponent. I mean inequality, that you wrote. It's easy prove it?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: use Dirichlet's test. See more at [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_test)

It's clear that $\left\{\dfrac 1 {\sqrt{n^2 + 2}}\right\}$ is monotonic and converges to 0

Now the task is to prove $-\cos 3 + \cos 6 - \cos 9 + \cos 12 + ...$ is bounded

Recognize that $\cos 6 - \cos 3 = -2\sin \frac 9 2 \sin \frac 3 2$

$\cos 12 - \cos 9 = -2\sin \frac {21} 2 \sin \frac 3 2$

$\cos 18 - \cos 15 = -2\sin \frac {33} 2 \sin \frac 3 2$

and $-2 \sin 3\left(\sin \frac 9 2 + \sin \frac {21} 2 + \sin \frac {33} 2 ... \right)= \cos \frac {15} 2 - \cos \frac 3 2 + \cos \frac {27} 2 - \cos \frac {15} 2 +...$

You can see that $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{2n} (-1)^k \cos {3k} = \dfrac{\sin \frac 3 2}{\sin 3} \left|\cos(2n + 1.5) - \cos 1.5 \right|$, which is always bounded

Therefore the series converges